# Configure htlatex with listings to use Javascript renderer

Tags: htlatex

I have a document using a custom environment in the listings package. So I have code embedded like so

```
\begin{tawny}
(println "hello")
\end{tawny}
```

My plan is to use some Javascript syntax high-lighter to render this. So I have added this into my cf.cfg file.

```
\Preamble{html}
\ConfigureEnv{tawny}
{\HCode{<stuff>}}
{\HCode{</stuff>}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Obviously I want to change  to something sane later. At the moment, though, this does not seem to be affected the rendering of the {tawny} environment. Have I got something wrong with my cf.cfg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have an answer. First the config must come before 
the \begin{document} section in cf.cfg. And second, I need
to switch listings off for HTML or I get my markup AND everything else.

So, minimal small.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifx \HCode\Undef
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{tawny}{\lstset{language=lisp}}{}
\else
\newenvironment{tawny}%
{}%
{}%
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{tawny}
(println "hello")
\end{tawny}

\end{document}
```

Minimal cf.cfg

```
\Preamble{html}
\ConfigureEnv{tawny}
{\HCode{<stuff>}}
{\HCode{</stuff>}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Which after

```
htlatex small cf
```

produces

```
<!--l. 14--><p class="noindent" ><stuff>(println &#8221;hello&#8221;)</stuff>
```

Obviously, I intend to replace "stuff" within something useful to get the
source highlighter to work.

I'd rather not have the non-breaking spaces, but I can live with this.